# In C++ called from Lua, lua_type(L,0) returns 9 which isn't documented

Tags: c++, lua

I'm using Lua as scripting language in my (C++) game.
In one call (from lua to c++) I check what type is on the top of the stack:

```
if(lua_type(L, (0)) == LUA_TSTRING)
```

But sometimes lua_type(L, (0)) returns 9.

I can't seem to find any references to this (return values should be between -1 and 8 or LUA_TNONE, LUA_TNIL, ... LUA_TTHREAD).

What's happening?

Comment: Ive found the following in lobject.h:
    `/*
    ** Extra tags for non-values
    */
    #define LUA_TPROTO LUA_NUMTAGS
    #define LUA_TUPVAL (LUA_NUMTAGS+1)
    #define LUA_TDEADKEY (LUA_NUMTAGS+2)`

Where `LUA_NUMTAGS` is 9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top of the stack is at index -1, not 0.

0 can never be used as an index for accessing the stack:

> (Note that 0 is never an acceptable index.)

in [§4.3 – Valid and Acceptable Indices](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4.3) in the reference manual.

The C API in Lua does not hold the programmer's hand:

> As in most C libraries, the Lua API functions do not check their arguments for validity or consistency. However, you can change this behavior by compiling Lua with the macro LUA_USE_APICHECK defined. [[§4](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4.3)]

Comment: Still, the documentation says that `LUA_TNONE` therefore should be the result, yet `LUA_TNONE` is -1, not 9. It could be that they consider this scenario (non-existent rather than simply "invalid" index) to not even be covered by that error case, and as such this becomes UB. Seems like poor coding if that's true, though.

Comment: While I agree that this doesn't explain the exact return value once you've hit undefined behavior anything is acceptable and `lua_type` is explicitly documented as being defined for "acceptable ind[ices]" or ("valid" or "non-valid (but acceptable) ind[ices]".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You do realize that the set of people comprising "they" in terms of lua is a set that contains lhf, right? =)

Comment: `9` comes from [LUA_TPROTO](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lobject.h.html#LUA_TPROTO), an internal tag, probably a value in a different stack frame.

Comment: Right, so it's the distinction between "acceptable" and "valid" indices. I'm not a Lua programmer.

Comment: It is the difference between "accetable" and "not acceptable" indices. The return value is defined (in lua 5.3) for all "acceptable" indices (valid or not). Using any other value is UB.